# importing a tkinter entry input variable to another python file

Tags: python, tkinter, python-import, importerror

I have a file a.py which is my app gui. I would like to import some variables given by tkinter entry input from this a.py to another python file b.py whenever I press the submit button.

I have tried using global and other solutions on stackoverflow but nothing works.

**a.py**

```
class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    
    self.entry1 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self,
    self.entry1.place(x, y)

    self.halo_button_2 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="Create Halos",width=200, height=50, command = self.run_halos)
    self.halo_button_2.place(relx=0.50, rely=0.87, anchor='center')

    def run_halos(self):
        
        global z0,zf,samples,steps,Mlim,Mmin,Mmax
        z0 = self.entry1.get()

        os.system('python b.py')
```

This then runs the **b.py** file:

```
from a import z0
```

this gives an error: **cannot import name 'z0' from 'a'**

or

```
from a.App import z0
```

error: **No module named a.App**, 'halo' is not a package

or

```
from a import App
from App import z0
```

error: **No module named 'App'**

Can't seem to find the issue. I am relatively new with python classes and tkinter. Thank you in advance.